# What is the best way to store runtime information in SQLalchemy model?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

What is the best way to store runtime information in model?
And is it good idea to store one in a model(like online/offline, etc)

for example:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    fullname = Column(String, default='')
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    role = Column(String, nullable=False)
    status = {0: "Offline", 1: "Online", -1: "Unknown"}

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Base.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.init_status()

    @orm.reconstructor
    def init_status(self):
        self._online = 0

    @property
    def online(self):
        if self._online is None:
            self._online = 0
        if self.enable:
            return self._online
        return -1

    @online.setter
    def online(self, value):
        if value != self.online:
            dispatcher.send(sender=self, signal="state", value=value)
            self._online = value
```

If I get object from session like
user = session.query(User).get(1)
change state
user.online = 1
and after session.close() I have detached object

Do I always have to do expunge(user) after commit() and before close()
and then if I want to change it, I have to add it to new session and the again commit,expunge,close

Is there any other ways?

P.S.
what is the most used practice, to create DAO layer or session it self work like DAO layer?

I need to have access to this state in a whole life of app, but as I undestand it's not a good way to use one session all time.
Proper way, to open session, do all my stuff with DB, then close session. But then I lost my state.

In java I have DAO layer and business object, that store all my db field and all my states regardless of session.
but with SA I already have session, DBO object and Manager object. I dont want to create so much layers, I think its not much pythonic.

Thanks.

Comment: Please realize that some of your questions are very subjective. There is no "best" architecture for an application. How many developers do you have? What are their experiences? Is this a web backend? For a Web API or a web site? Or perhaps a desktop application? Adding a DAO layer might add a layer of inderection/reduce cohesion, but it also increases the number of parts into your system and could make your code more difficult to understand. My advice: just do it. You're over-analyzing things if you think there is one "best" way to do things. Trust your instincts, and learn from your mistakes.

Answer (score -1):

You should store the status also in DB instead of memory.

As its not user data, preferably a different table, UserSession which has a user id FK.
If you do so, you can store other data as well e.g lastlogintime. 
And even make intelligent decisions like if the lastlogintime > 30 mins, you can change the status back to offline maybe.

Storing such state in memory is not a good idea.